# Java: multiple packages minimum working example

Tags: java

Trying to understand how Java packages work with classpath etc.  In ~/java/tmp/test/HelloWorld I created HelloWorld.java:

```
package test;
import test2.Hello2;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello2 x = new Hello2();
        x.blagh(args);
    }
}
```

Then in ~/java/tmp/test2/Hello2 I created Hello2.java:

```
package test2;
public class Hello2
{
    public static void blagh(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

Working in ~/java/tmp, I try to compile using:

```
javac -g test/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.java
```

I get the following errors:

```
test/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.java:3: package test2 does not exist
import test2.Hello2;
            ^
test/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.java:8: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Hello2
location: class test.HelloWorld
        Hello2 x = new Hello2();
        ^
test/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.java:8: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Hello2
location: class test.HelloWorld
        Hello2 x = new Hello2();
```

I've tried things like setting the classpath (to every possible combination of the above paths I could think of), changing which directory I run the compiler from, etc.  Nothing works.  Please help.

Comment: 1. Use an IDE. 2: you have to feed both source files to javac. how could it possibly know where test2 is if you only feed it test?

Comment: I have developing java since 1997. In all but a handful of times I use an IDE.  Do yourself a favour an use one, so you can focus upon good design and good coding rather than the infrastructure of package layout.

Comment: I prefer the command line.  It is not that hard.  From `~/tmp/java`:  `javac test/*.java test2/*.java` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `HelloWorld.java` belongs to package `test`, so it should live in a directory named `test`, not `test/HelloWorld`. Same with `Hello2.java`, it should live in `test2`, not `test2/Hello2`. Move `HelloWorld.java` to the `test` directory and `Hello2.java` to the `test2` directory and give it another try.

Comment: +1 Always nice to answer the question instead of chewing someone out for something irrelevant like not using an IDE.